# Solving financial mathematics using a graphing calculator

Tags: finance

**Merlin spends six weeks at his cabin every summer. He loves to go fishing and he has decided that he wants his oenter preformatted text herewn boat this summer instead of going fishing with his neighbour all the time. He could purchase a used boat for $5000. He would use his line of credit which has an interest rate of 5.6% compounded monthly. He would make a monthly payment for the next two years to pay off his line of credit.**

I'm having trouble using my graphing calculator (TI-84 Plus) to answer this question. I'm not sure where to place the numbers to get the correct answer. If someone can help explain to me where the numbers go it wold be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that you can accept (good) answers?